# Did the Ryan family leave a footprint in England when immigrating to New Zealand in 1875 and 1883?

Tags: england, immigration, ireland

I’m researching how my Ryan family left Ireland. Jeremiah (Jerry, Joseph) Ryan and Mary Hayes took 3 children Bridget (Bid), Honora (Norah) and Thomas Ryan. Martin Frances Ryan stayed behind. They were living around Drumwood/Chadville/Clonganhue in Tipperary.

They arrived in Wellington, New Zealand, 22, May 1875 on the Hindostan. Total cost to the NZ Government: 43 pounds, 10 shillings. On the same ship, there was the Power family, of which one is/becomes a Priest and marries Martin Frances Ryan in NZ.

The ship originally left Gravesend, England on 10 Feb 1875. https://www.familysearch.org/search/ark:/61903/3:1:S3HY-DTB3-7NV?i=4&cc=1609792

Martin Frances Ryan (age 18) left a few years later to join with his family. He arrived in Wellington, New Zealand on 17 Feb 1884 by British Queen. The cost to NZ government: 15 pounds.

The British Queen left London on 28th December 1883 and Plymouth at 6.30 p.m. on the following day. My guess Martin was at Plymouth (any evidence?). https://www.familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:FSBY-FYZ

Family tree:
https://www.ancestry.com.au/family-tree/tree/120872934/family?cfpid=201001876033

I don’t know when any of the family left Ireland. The last known location before England was on the 14th Dec 1873, when Thomas Ryan was born in Clonganhue, Co Tipperary, Ireland.

Is there any evidence of the family footprint being in England?

Comment: Don't forget to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format which is quite different from bulletin boards, discussion forums and other Q&A sites you may be used to.  Please try to ask a single focussed question rather than multiple questions in one.

Comment: I have edited to only have one question at the end.

Comment: Just a reminder that only Ancestry subscribers can view your tree. You've done a pretty good job putting the critical information into your question. Links to live trees are generally not useful for our purposes because we'd like to see a snapshot of the information you had when you started thinking about the question. (You can always add more information to your question in an update as needed.)

Comment: I think you just need a free account. But the tree is just a bonus link. I'm happy to answer any questions if needed.

Comment: You said you don't know when the family left Ireland, but have you worked out any kind of timeframe? I know it's tough because of the record loss!  What's the latest event you have for the family in Ireland?

Comment: I have a free (registered user) Ancestry account and I'm still getting the nag screen.

Comment: Oh, that's annoying (some have accessed it without a subscription).
The last known location was on 14 Dec 1873 when Thomas Ryan was born in Clonganhue, Co Tipperary, Ireland. I'll add that above.